# What to do with duplicate Q's that don't actually seem like duplicates?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki, question-quality, duplicate-answers

In SO one question is marked as a duplicate, but it looks like an unrelated issue with the same symptom as the linked. The code in the question is not nice or clean and the question for some reason has 22 mostly useless revs by the OP that makes the question a wiki - which I also think is just plain wrong and I did flag to get it unwikified, but to no avail.

The user could try to make better questions and not edit one character at a time, but still I think this question is salvageable. How should this be reacted to?

[Link to SO question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17516175/submit-button-needs-to-be-clicked-twice-on-ie)

Answer (score 1):

actually there is much question that i see every day marked as duplicated but when i look to the question link on the duplicated question

i see no answer that related with the question that just marked as a duplicated ... started to think that its going randomly only if some things are the same or names are the same its get marked

but if you look and Focus on it you will actually find out that the question is 60% different 
and the answer should be some how like 80% difference

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't answer the question: "What should be done about it?"

Comment: @doubleDown DoubleCheck Both Question And Wait For Answers Then Look If The Answers Is The Same Then Its A Duplicated `:D`

Answer (score 1):

i dont see why should mac answer be a community wiki it makes no sense

> update your Function like this
>
> ***function*** *handleBrowse()
>
> {
>
> $('#uploadedfile').click();
>
> $('#uploadedfile').detach();
>
> }*
> **hope this helps you.**

Comment: I think it's a community wiki because the question is community wiki - yeah and I think that is wrong too. What should I do about it?

Comment: How does this answer the question on what to do with the "duplicate" question?